# Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ then does there exist $i\in \{1,2...,n\}$ such that $H=\mathbb{Stab}(i)$?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of order $(n-1)!$ in $S_n$ then does there exist $i\in \{1,2...,n\}$ such that $H=\mathbb{Stab}(i)$ ?

My motivation behind asking this question comes from a question on Galois theory, which is "Show that given any integer $n \geq 1$ there exist a field extension $F \subset K$ of degree $n$ with no intermediate fields". Although I've solved without using the problem I've asked, but not getting whether the problem I asked is correct or not ?

Comment: This is true for all $n$  except $n=6$. When $n=6$ the subgroup ${\rm PGL}(2,5)$ has order $5!$ and does not fix a point.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, this is true except for $n=6$. There is an old result of Jordan from 1873 that could be used to prove it.

If a transitive subgroup of $S_n$ has an element of order $p$ where $p$ is a prime with $n/2 < p < n-2$ then $G=A_n$ or $S_n$.

Let $H \le S_n$ with $|H|=(n-1)!$. If $H$ and fixes a subset of size $m$, then $|H| \le m!(n-m)!$, which is less that $(n-1)!$ unless $m=1$, in which case $H$ stabilizes a point.

So we can assume that $H$ is transitive, but now, when $n \ge 8$, there is a prime $p$ dividing $|H|$ with $n/2 < p < n-2$, and Jordan's result gives a contradiction.

You can do the other cases $n=7$ and $n\le 5$ individually.